# How apply once scenario to list elements?

Tags: mocking, stubbing, wiremock

I have list elements (10-50 elements) and one method, which change state of element. They have three states: start, active, stop, I joined them in a scenario.

But after call this method (three times), method return 404 error and I restarted scenario, this is very uncomfortable.

Method for different elements not unique, i.e. calls one for each.

```
  {
  "scenarioName": "scenario",
  "requiredScenarioState": "Started",
  "newScenarioState": "wait_start",
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "urlPathPattern": "/cashboxes/[0-9]+/registration/[0-9]+"
  },

  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "fixedDelayMilliseconds": 3000,
    "jsonBody": {
      "id": "$(registration_id)",
      "cashbox_id": "$(cashbox_id)",
      "status": "start"
    },
    "transformers": ["body-transformer"],
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
  {
  "scenarioName": "scenario",
  "requiredScenarioState": "wait_start",
  "newScenarioState": "wait_active",
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "urlPathPattern": "/cashboxes/[0-9]+/registration/[0-9]+"
  },

  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "fixedDelayMilliseconds": 3000,
    "jsonBody": {
      "id": "$(registration_id)",
      "cashbox_id": "$(cashbox_id)",
      "status": "active"
    },
    "transformers": ["body-transformer"],
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
  {
  "scenarioName": "scenario",
  "requiredScenarioState": "wait_active",
  "newScenarioState": "wait_stop",
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "urlPathPattern": "/cashboxes/[0-9]+/registration/[0-9]+"
  },

  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "fixedDelayMilliseconds": 3000,
    "jsonBody": {
      "id": "$(registration_id)",
      "cashbox_id": "$(cashbox_id)",
      "status": "stop"
    },
    "transformers": ["body-transformer"],
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there soluction for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to expectation a Scenario does not reset to it's 'started' state after a completion of the scenario. It requires the reset of *all* the scenarios to reset a *single* scenario.

In my mind auto-reset of the scenario is something that should be expected behavior when WireMock is running permanently in a standalone fashion.

My recommendation is to create an issue on the GitHub project page and if possible to create Pull Request with the solution if that is within your capabilities.